# React addons transition group & react router - JS page transition animating

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do you use the JS variant of Transition Group with React Router. I have the code shown below in the top level react router componenent but the `componentWillLeave()` event doesn't fire in child routes:

```
<TransitionGroup>
    {this.props.children}
</TransitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving the routes an key solved the issue:

```
const ChildRoutes = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
            key: this.props.location.pathname,
        })
```